# Including helpers when rendering a template/partial by hand

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use the following code to render a template to a string that I can use later on:

```
renderer = ActionView::Base.new(MyApp::Application.config.view_path)
# INCLUDE HELPERS HERE
data = renderer.render(:partial => template, :locals => locals)
```

However, I want to be able to access some helpers (actually all). In rails 2.3 I was able to do this:

```
renderer.extend ApplicationController.master_helper_module
```

However, as of Rails 3, this no longer works. So, how do I make my helper methods available to use in my template?

Comment: Why would you want to render a template to a string ???

Comment: Actually, I am rendering to a file, that is later passsed on to a command line utility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to look at `abstract_controller/rendering.rb` It looks like in rails 3 we should be able to do something like this:

```
renderer = ApplicationController.view_context_class.new(...)
```

And the module `master_helper_module` is now accessed by name `_helpers`, and it should be already included in `view_context_class`

Comment: Thankyou, works like a charm! I actually ended up including a single helper in order to group functionality, but this is good to know.